# Google shared drives to BigQuery connector

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I want to write a python connector which will be moving new added CSVs on Google Drive (Shared drives) to BigQuery.

I know [Loading data into BigQuery from Drive is not currently supported, but you can query data in Drive by using an external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data).

For example from GC Storage it is very easy to make an automatic flow of data, but not sure how to connect to Google Drive API (shared drives), search for new added CSVs (in many directories) and add them as tables to BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to search for newly added CSV's and directories in BigQuery. If you look at [the documentation for querying Google Drive in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#creating_and_querying_a_permanent_external_table) you'll see that you need to specify the Drive URI to query a table in Google Drive, which is unique for each file.

You could use an AppScript in Google Drive to accomplish this though. Check out [this post](https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/how-to-load-google-shared-drive-files-to-google-bigquery-fac22c11ef9e) for a tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to load it to BQ without downloading to local? Thanks to post you mentioned I listed all csv's IDs that I need to upload to BQ. I filtered them by modification date and parent folder. Right now I have the Drive URIs to files and not sure how to use it

Comment: OK, I guess I have it - I query CSV on drive from BigQuery like temporary table, select all of the rows to df and then load the table from dataframe

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to load the external table into a non-external, proper table? You could use a Pandas dataframe for that or just do something like `CREATE TABLE my_dataset.my_non_external_table AS SELECT * FROM my_dataset.my_external_table`

Comment: Ok, based on the article you suggested, I wrote mine describing my use case: [Upload Data from Google Shared Drive to BigQuery](https://ijaniszewski.medium.com/upload-data-from-google-shared-drive-to-bigquery-python-connector-46b044b59630)